# Scatter plot in racket with individual colors

Tags: plot, racket

I am exploring the plotting utilities in `racket`, and I have to say, so far I am incredibly impressed. However, I ran into a small difficulty.

I was trying to make a scatter plot, where each point has its own color (for visualizing classification algorithms). However, I am not sure how to make each point have its own color. Is it possible?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
(define (random-choice l)
  (list-ref l (random (length l))))

(define (scatter data)
  (let ([x-max (apply max (map first data))]
        [x-min (apply min (map first data))]
        [y-max (apply max (map second data))]
        [y-min (apply min (map second data))]
        [colors (build-list 20 
            ; here I am trying to create a list of desired colors
            ; ,but an error tells me that only single elements are accepted
            (λ _ (random-choice (list "red" "blue")))])
    (parameterize ([plot-new-window? #t]
                   [point-sym 'dot]
                   [point-size 20])
      (plot (points data
            #:color colors)
            #:x-max x-max
            #:x-min x-min
            #:y-max y-max
            #:y-min y-min))))
```

A rough equivalent in `R` would be:

```
c <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
colors <- sample(c("red","blue"),10,replace=TRUE)
plot(c$y,c$x,col=colors)
```

By the way, I would welcome any (and all) comments on my `racket` code, such as simplifying the boundary specification for the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`plot`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/plotting.html?q=plot#%28def._%28%28lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt%29._plot%29%29) function accepts a list of renderers (more generally, a [tree of](http://docs.racket-lang.org/unstable/contract.html#%28def._%28%28lib._unstable%2Fcontract..rkt%29._treeof%29%29) renderers), and each individual renderer can be supplied with its own color.

Additionally, since Plot 5.2, the `plot` function will automatically scale the bounds of the plot to fit the data, if possible. Obviously, this doesn't work with things like `(function sin)`, which is unbounded, but for `points` data, the automatic scaling is sufficient if custom bounds are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

With @Alexis King's suggestions, I ended up with this for a *simple case of two groups*. Writing down for posterity.

```
(define-struct datum [point label])

(define (color-scatter data)
  (let-values 
      ([(group-a group-b) (partition (λ (x) (= 1 (datum-label x))) data)])
    (plot (list
           (points (map datum-point group-a) #:color "red")
           (points (map datum-point group-b) #:color "blue")))))
```